# Upper and Lower limit calculation in Microsoft excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have mean value in A1 like 2.3 and plus or minus tolerance value in A2 like ±0.02. I need to calculate upper and lower limit at A3 and A4 column. Is there any formula to calculate automatically? I have a huge list of numbers. Please help me

My Input:
A1:2.3     A2:±0.02      A3:=2.3+0.02           A4:=2.3-0.02

I want to automate A3 and A4 will result automatically if I enter mean and tolerance value
note
Always there is ± symbol in tolerance column

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
in cell A3 =A1+mid(A2,2,10) and in cell A4 =A1-mid(A2,2,10)
```

Then drag down or select cells, enter formula and ctrl+enter, may need to convert the mid result to value as I have not tested this. Tested and works.